# How do I determine what benefits I could claim?

Tags: moving, welfare-benefits

I work and my girlfriend is on benefits. Recently I have been staying for free with family and friends (not paying rent or contributing to bills). I want to move into my girlfriend's house.

How do I determine the situation with benefits: will it affect her benefits if I move in with her, are there any benefits I could claim, how would I find out how to claim them?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Personal Finance.

Comment: Hello new user, what country is this in?  USA or ??

Comment: I've heavily edited the post to make it answerable here. The answer still depends on where you are in the world, but in a moment I will add an answer for the UK.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, the Government maintains a list of [independent benefit calculators](https://www.gov.uk/benefits-calculators) that will let you put in the details of your situation and calculate what you can claim. I would suggest calculating this for you both living separately, and then again for you living together, and work out whether you are better off to move in with her or not. Once you've worked out what you could claim, the details of how to claim are also on the [gov.uk website](https://www.gov.uk/browse/benefits).

If this is too difficult for you to do on your own, you could get help from [Citizen's Advice](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/).